# ScrollView onclick set the visibility to be Visible

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview

I have got this Scroll View in my android app and what I am trying to do is set its visibility to be gone. When you click on this button with an id clickme it should change the visibility of the scroll view and set it to be Visible. However when I trying to do this I am getting the error sayign "Unfortunately, ExampleApp has stopped". Basically crashes. 
this is my code for the button;

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lastmonth"

                android:id="@+id/lastmonth"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
```

this is the code for the scroll view

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollview"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/scrollvisibility">

<LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/exampletext"
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:textColor="#ff010101"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

this is the code that I have got in my activity;

```
final View v = null;

 v.findViewById(R.id.scrollvisibility).setVisibility(View.GONE);


v.findViewById(R.id.lastMonthButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Testing","Button Clicked");
            //v.findViewById(R.id.scrollvisibility).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does `v` represent here? And can you post the logcat from the crash?

Comment: `lastMonthButton` what is this?

Comment: The problem is that you set `v` to `null` then immediately try to use it so you get a `NPE`. What exactly are you doing here? And can you post a little more code so we have some context of where this is and what's going on?

Comment: @codeMagic - see below for the problem & solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a debug session with the OP - the error seems quite clear now! The onClickListener onClick method simply override the current fragment view so when using `v.findViewById()` - it was using the wrong view.

```
v.findViewById(R.id.lastMonthButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Testing","Button Clicked");
            v.findViewById(R.id.scrollvisibility).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

The fix was to rename `onClick(View v) -> onClick(View view)` or to instantiated `View scroller =  v.findViewById(R.id.scrollvisibility);` and access the object from within the `onClick()`

Answer (score 0):

As codeMagic pointed out, you have set a `final v = null`, which means that you will get a `NullPointerException`.

To access the button use `Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lastMonthButton);`
Then you can set the visibility as you wish.

Also, in the `onClick` method, the button can be accessed as `b`, because it was declared in the method that contains it.

EDIT:
The second `LinearLayout` doesn't accomplish anything, and I think that you can set the visibility directly in the `ScrollView` instead of hiding only the `LinearLayout`